# T-SQL group by a key that is a parent in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm trying to write a query where I want to return the user that has the highest number of contributions to a certain table. To keep the case simple let's imagine many users can write many paragraphs that are eventually shown as a complete story. Below is the table structure (I'm given this structure, not my design but I have structured the column names at least ;))

```
paragraphs
-----
id (PK)
story_id (imaginary FK that I need to group the results by)
user_id (FK to userprop.id)
body
date

userprop
----
id (PK)
supervisor_id (FK to supervisors.id)
username (FK to users.name)

users
----
name
full_name

supervisors
----
id
full_name
```

I'm trying to write a query where I get each paragraph but with two extra columns showing the supervisors name that is used most times and the actual count of the supervisors' supervisions.

I've been fiddling with inner join subqueries, trying to subquery my way in the main select to the result and trying to group by a subquery. Some of the approaches are not even valid SQL and others didn't work out yet since I'm unsure how to group by `supervisors.id` through `userprop.supervisor_id` which is linked to `paragraphs.user_id` by `userprop.id`.

Can this be done in a single query, or do I have to incorporate some PHP and use multiple queries and some loops?

I have read only access to the database.

Sample data:

```
paragraphs
id  story_id    user_id body
----------------------------
1   1           1       Sample data
2   1           1       Sample data
3   2           1       Sample data
4   1           2       Sample data
5   1           3       Sample data
6   5           1       Sample data

userprop
id  supervisor_id   username
----------------------------
1   1               user_abc
2   1               user_def
3   2               user_ghi

users
name        full_name
---------------------
user_abc    Jack Jackson
user_def    Bill Winters
user_ghi    Sharon Staples

supervisors
id  full_name
1   Steve Doppler
2   Frank Frampton

expected output
id  story_id    user_id body        main_supervisor_count   main_supervisor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1           1       Sample data 3                       Steve Doppler
2   1           1       Sample data 3                       Steve Doppler
3   2           1       Sample data 1                       Steve Doppler
4   1           2       Sample data 3                       Steve Doppler
5   1           3       Sample data 1                       Frank Frampton
6   5           1       Sample data 1                       Steve Doppler
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a simple [partitioned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) `COUNT` is all you need.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @paragraphs TABLE (id int, story_id int, user_id int, body nvarchar(max));
INSERT INTO @paragraphs(id, story_id, user_id, body) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'Sample data'),
(2, 1, 1, 'Sample data'),
(3, 2, 1, 'Sample data'),
(4, 1, 2, 'Sample data'),
(5, 1, 3, 'Sample data'),
(6, 5, 1, 'Sample data');

DECLARE @userprop TABLE (id int, supervisor_id int, username nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO @userprop (id, supervisor_id, username) VALUES
(1, 1, 'user_abc'),
(2, 1, 'user_def'),
(3, 2, 'user_ghi');

DECLARE @supervisors TABLE (id int, full_name nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO @supervisors (id, full_name) VALUES
(1, 'Steve Doppler'),
(2, 'Frank Frampton');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    paragraphs.id
    ,paragraphs.story_id
    ,paragraphs.user_id
    ,paragraphs.body
    ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY paragraphs.story_id, supervisors.id) AS main_supervisor_count
    ,supervisors.full_name AS main_supervisor
FROM
    @paragraphs AS paragraphs
    INNER JOIN @userprop AS userprop ON userprop.id = paragraphs.user_id
    INNER JOIN @supervisors AS supervisors ON supervisors.id = userprop.supervisor_id
ORDER BY
    paragraphs.id;
```

**Result**

```
+----+----------+---------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| id | story_id | user_id |    body     | main_supervisor_count | main_supervisor |
+----+----------+---------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
|  1 |        1 |       1 | Sample data |                     3 | Steve Doppler   |
|  2 |        1 |       1 | Sample data |                     3 | Steve Doppler   |
|  3 |        2 |       1 | Sample data |                     1 | Steve Doppler   |
|  4 |        1 |       2 | Sample data |                     3 | Steve Doppler   |
|  5 |        1 |       3 | Sample data |                     1 | Frank Frampton  |
|  6 |        5 |       1 | Sample data |                     1 | Steve Doppler   |
+----+----------+---------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: This works so much better than a query I came up with (and lost due too machine freeze..) My solution incorporated a subquery as an inner join, with another subquery to get to the supervisors id with some grouping, filtering and ordering. I'm not sure what `count (*) over (partition by ...` does but will consult the manual right away. +1A

Comment: @Ben, read about "window functions" AKA "OVER clause". `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY paragraphs.story_id, supervisors.id)` returns number of rows in the result set for the same values of `paragraphs.story_id, supervisors.id`. In other words, result set is partitioned by `paragraphs.story_id, supervisors.id`.